# In Guava cache what is the default value for refreshAfterWrite when creating a LoadingCache without providing it

Tags: java, guava

What is the default value for refreshAfterWrite when creating a LoadingCache without providing it.

```
cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(new CacheLoader<Object, Object>() {
  @Override
  public Object load(Object o) throws Exception {
    return getObj(o);
  }

  @Override
  public ListenableFuture<Object> reload(Object o) throws Exception {
    final ListenableFutureTask<Object> task = ListenableFutureTask.create(() -> {
      return getObj(o);
    });
    executor.execute(task);
    return task;
  }
});
```

I see in the debug that the refreshAfterWrite is -1, but what does it means? It means it will never reload?

Comment: As both [`CacheBuilder.refreshAfterWrite(long,TimeUnit)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/27.0.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#refreshAfterWrite-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) and [`CacheBuilder.refreshAfterWrite(Duration)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/27.0.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#refreshAfterWrite-java.time.Duration-) say they'll throw an exception if the duration is negative, it's probable  the default negative value means the refresh mechanism is not enabled.

Comment: I've made some simple local tests and it seems like it will never refresh like @Slaw mentioned. I couldn't find this in Guava cache documentation so it would be good to have this information there.

Comment: If you don't ask it to refresh, it won't refresh.  If you do, it will.  That's pretty standard for a builder: you only have a setting if you set it.

Answer (score 0):

I can read from [this](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/3369) issue that:

> It's documented that if no options are set, a cache created by
> CacheBuilder will never do any kind of eviction. This applies to
> refresh as well, as it is a form of eviction.